# Better ASP.Net Form Post Mousetrap

Tags: asp.net

I have a webform with many input, checkbox, hidden, etc... elements and I am wondering if there is a best way to handle processing this.  Right now I have to check every form element to make sure it has been filled out, that it is valid, and then update the db.  I know there must be a better way, so I am looking for how others handle this situation.  Thanks.

Wade73

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Valdiation Server Controls such as [asp:RequiredFieldValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.requiredfieldvalidator.aspx) works well enough and does client side checking as well.

Beware, it breaks down if
- You don't actually buy into the entire architecture -- i.e. if you ignore Page.IsValid, or customize until you aren't actually using the validation patterns anymore.
- If your validation is much more complicated than a few checks
- If you don't like how tightly this binds your UI to business logic.

Avoid the [Validation Application Block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648831.aspx)-- it is a very peculiar solution because it requires expressing validations in attributes, which is great fun until a validation gets complicated or involves if's and loop's and multiple fields.

Comment: Sorry it took so long to get back to you, but I kept putting it off until I have a bit more time.  What about dealing with the post portion?  Is there some way to have the post variables assigned to corresponding fields on your model?

Comment: Um, that's a different question. Now you're asking about data binding. You may want to ask a separate question on how to do 2 way databinding. Outside of following naming conventions and using reflection to map controls to properties, it is hard to keep away from writing a line of code for each control and model property.